# C# nested array of string in appconfig

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, nested-lists

Quite new to C# and learning by making an a basic app (.net 3.5) . I have a simple CSV combiner, and my plan was to pull out variables like the file location/headers into a configuration file outside of my exe build.

I assume that is where the app.config file comes in.

My intention is to have a multidimensional array like:

```
<configuration>
   <input>
      <job>
         <file name ="csv1.csv" location=@"C:/" header="a,b,c" realHeader="a,b,c" />
         <file name ="csv2.csv" location=@"C:/" header="a,b,c" realHeader="a,b,c" />
      </job>
   </input>
   <output>
      <file name ="output.csv" location=@"C:/" header="a,b,c" realHeader="a,b,c" />
   </output>
</configuration>
```

The ideal scenario is to keep the syntax formatting simple like the above so a non technical user can use it, and to not define every single file (above example has two input files, I wanted to make my code just loop through all file tags so I could have many input files)

Is something like this even possible?
So far, I've just seen examples of config section which seems like I have to create multiple groups for each file tag which doesn't seem ideal

Any advice would be appreciated

In terms of accessing the values, In my head, I had something like:

```
List<string> files = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["input"];

Foreach ( var file in files){
....use file.location and other attributes....
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify-- You are wanting to find the `file path` of a file? And then find the `headers` _within_ the file (i.e `Column1, Column2, Column3`)?

Comment: @symon all the information would be in the configuration (filename, location, headers used, etc). So my intention is to loop through all file tags and access all the attributes of each file tag

Comment: So in my loop through all the files, I would set temporary variables for filename/location/headers/etc, process that file, then move on to the next file, reassign variables for this new file, process that file too, and so on

Comment: I was thinking of maybe giving up on "apps.config" and just create my own json/XML file

What would be the difference between the config file and these? Speed?